# No entiendo por qué java me muestra el mensaje de este código

Tags: java

Mi problema es muy sencillo, resulta que cuando pregunto un parámetro al usuario ,Java me ejecuta un `If` que no debería de ejecutarse, miren les muestro el fragmento de código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int op=0;  
    String dato; 
    do{ 

        try{ 
            dato=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Seleccionar una operacion:\n "
         + "1.- Suma\n"
         + "2.- Limite\n"
         + "3.- Resta\n"
         + "4.- multiplicacion\n"
         + "5.- Salir"       
            );  
            op=Integer.parseInt(dato);

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex){ 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ingresar una opcion entre 1 y 5"); 
        }

        if(op<=0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ingrese valores positivos entre 1 y 5");
    }
```

Ok, ahora supongamos que pedimos un número al usuario, y el usuario ingresó esto "AJHKHDAS", entonces el try - catch haría su trabajo, y Java únicamente debería mostrar este mensaje:

```
catch(NumberFormatException ex){ 
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ingresar una opcion entre 1 y 5"); 
}
```

Aquí es donde viene el problema por alguna extraña razón, después de mostrar el primer mensaje, que en teoría es correcto, me muestra el mensaje del `if` que le sigue, que vendría siendo este:

```
 if(op<=0){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ingrese valores positivos entre 1 y 5");
 }
```

y no entiendo por qué lo hace, ya que en ningún momento ingresé un numero menor o igual que cero, esa es mi única duda, que el usuario al ingresar caracteres no me debería mostrar el `if` que viene debajo.

Comment: Hola Nine, sinceramente no entiendo prácticamente nada de lo que comentas. Intenta formatear bien la pregunta por favor.

Comment: Miquel Coll, perdona que no fuera mas explicito, ya reformule mi pregunte, ojala y puedas entenderle mejor, soy nuevo en esto y lamento no saber expresarme, ojala y ahora se mas entendible.

Comment: No te preocupes. Ahora está mejor pero aún falta un poquito. En media hora te ayudo un poco a formatear y a ver qué pasa.

Comment: Me parece excelente, en si mi problema es muy sencillo, solo que no entiendo por que ejecuta ese if, de cualquier forma, yo espero con gusto, no te prisa y muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia de ayudarme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al comienzo del programa le estas dando a OP el valor 0. Cuando salta la excepcion no se llega a dar ningun valor nuevo a OP por lo tanto cuando llega al IF, como OP sigue valiendo 0 entra.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias, ya me imaginaba que seria algo muy sencillo, te agradezco por toda la ayuda, enserio, apenas estoy aprendiendo a programar y sigue estando muy verde en esto, pero espero mejorar con el tiempo :)

Comment: @Nine Si esto responde tu pregunta, entonces deberías aceptar la respuesta  http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Si, perdona me fui a comer, lo siento , ya quedo , gracias :D

Answer (score 2):

Fíjate que estás inicializando la variable "op" a 0, por tanto al entrar en el try catch como salta al error, la variable "op" no cambia su estado, en consecuencia "op" sigue siendo 0 y al llegar a ese "if" la condición es correcta

Comment: Muchas Gracias tambien, ya encontre mi error, ya pude correjir el problemas, gracias.